# NativeModules.CallDetectionManagerAndroid is null

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-modules

I try to use the package "react-native-call-detection" in my react-native project.
But I got a problem. CallDetectorManager does not start listening to incoming calls.

And i found the problem in
https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/react-native-call-detection/blob/master/index.js

```
const NativeCallDetector = NativeModules.CallDetectionManager
const NativeCallDetectorAndroid = NativeModules.CallDetectionManagerAndroid
```

This constants is null both.
why could it be?

P.S.: I'm using expo.